# jQuery implementation - not all scripts work well

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, wordpress-theming

I make a site based on Wordpress and all my scripts use jQuery 2.1.4.

The problem is that when I implement jQuery in `<header>` section then 'scroll to top' works, but navigation (Bootstrap navwalker) does not. When I implement jQuery in `functions.php` then the navigation works but the 'scroll to top' doesn't!

I've tried to use another jQuery version for scroll to top with `noConflict` but then the nav doesn't work.

I've tried also to move all my scripts right after `<body>` and `<?php wp_head(); ?>` but it also doesn't work.

And when I implement jQuery in both `<head>` section and in the `functions.php` (just for the test), the nav doesn't function.

The code (like this the nav works and scroll to top doesn't work):

```
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>


<!-- scroll to top-->
 <script>   
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });

});
</script>    


 <?php wp_head(); ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
/* Theme setup */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpt_setup' );
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wpt_setup' ) ):
        function wpt_setup() {  
            register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary navigation', 'wptuts' ) );
        } endif;


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-2.1.4.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );



function wpt_register_js() { 
    wp_register_script('jquery.bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery-2.1.4.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap.min');   
} 

add_action( 'init', 'wpt_register_js' );
function wpt_register_css() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_template', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_css' );        

// Register custom navigation walker
    require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
?>
```

The nav code

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --> 
    <div class="navbar-header"> 
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>  
    </div> 
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --> 
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
      <?php /* Primary navigation */
      wp_nav_menu( array(
           'menu' => 'Menu 1',
        'depth' => 2,
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
        //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
        ?>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Output order of `<script>` tags:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../wp-content/themes/tyszka/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<!-- some plugin stuff here-->

<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href=".../xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href=".../wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.2.2" />

    <!-- scroll to top-->
     <script>   
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        //Click event to scroll to top
        $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
            return false;
        });

    });
    </script>    


  </head>
```

Comment: Where does `functions.php` get included? What does the navigation code look like? Would it be possible to replicate the problem in a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: functions.php is included automatically in WordPress, I don't have to implement it in `<head>` section. I think it would be rather hard to replicate it in JsFiddle because of this functions.php and navwalker... I've added the nav code to the question

Comment: Do you get any errors in console in both the cases?

Comment: Strictly speaking PHP processes HTML/CSS/Javascript. When you load up the page you are given the output, you could use that to create a JsFiddle. Regardless, i think we need to see an output order of the `<script>` tags...

Comment: I've added the output

Answer (score 0):

Keep the code as it is!

Just make a small change.
Put the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before your scroll script.

Don't include any extra jQuery files. I feel this should do the trick!!

Let us know!

**EDIT:**

Went through your site and this is what comes to my mind.
1. Bootstrap js loads before jQuery
2. there are 2 jquery files in the code

So I am not much of an expert in Wordpress, but I dug up something,
There are functions `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`
Both these functions have been used by you in the above code, but in those functions, there is a third parameter which accepts array and is used to pass dependencies. [Link 1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

If you pass jquery in an array, I think your issue should be resolved!
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, as I said, I've tried this already and it doesn't work.

Comment: When you write your code(as mentioned in the question), do u get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, I do. 
`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
75 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` (here begins my scroll to top)

Comment: But bootrap works so I don't know why there's an error. And the order of the *.js files is also correct.

Comment: Just saw the output you pasted. It is strange that the `jquery-2.1.4.min.js` is not coming in it

Comment: I didn't notice that!! Stupid me, I was sure it was there.
So my problem was that the jQuery was simply implemented wrong. I have to start studying PHP... thanks for the help;)

Comment: Now I don't get it - all the scripts work perfectly but there is still no jQuery in output and there is still the jQuery error in the console ;) How is that possible? And the gallery lightbox doesn't work... always something wrong.

Comment: My dear friend,kindly observe the second line of output!!

Comment: The bootstrap is not getting jquery but the rest of the scripts are, I think?

Comment: now Bootstrap works and scroll to top works but Gallery lightbox doesn't work. Please take a look: http://solutionsmvo.nazwa.pl/tyszka/

Comment: No success :(
I've updated my functions.php above, maybe I am doing something wrong, don't know PHP to well.

Comment: Try writing `wp_register_script('jquery.bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery-2.1.4.min.js')); `

Comment: This way the nav doesn't work... Well, I am done with it. I've changed the gallery plugin for another one and the gallery works. There must be a jQuery conflict but I have no more power for that.Thank you very very much!